Prove $ a+b+c \ge ab+bc+ca $ from $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$ (from AoPS discussion)
Let $a,b,c$ be positive reals such that $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$. In this AoPS discussion ( see comments by user "Entrepreneur") is claimed that it is possible to deduce from above assumption that
$$ a+b+c \ge ab+bc+ca $$
How to see it?
By easy application of AM-GM one can show $1 \ge abc$ and from this immediately $ab+bc+ca \ge 3$. From this its possible to show  $a+b+c \ge 3$, see eg here. But the claimed inequality above seemingly cannot be immediately extracted from this. Does somebody see how to get it?

First, check that the conditions $ab+bc+ac+abc=4$ and $\frac{a}{a+2}+\frac{b}{b+2}+\frac{c}{c+2}=1$ are equivalent.
Now, from Cauchy-Schwarz, we have
$$\sum \frac a{a+2} \ge \frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a^2+b^2+c^2+2(a+b+c)}$$
and hence the inequality follows.
The first equivalence is a well known trick and the Olympiad guys at AoPS probably recite these mantras every morning!

alright, I presumably see. Just to clarify here CS you apply to vectors $v:=(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}},\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}},\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}})$ and $w:= \frac{1}{\sum  a(a+2)}\cdot (\sqrt{a(a+2)},\sqrt{b(b+2)}, \sqrt{c(c+2)})$, right?

@user267839 $w:= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum  a(a+2)}}\cdot (\sqrt{a(a+2)},\sqrt{b(b+2)}, \sqrt{c(c+2)})$ And I feel like the $\sum$ a notation kind of confusing.

@athanoslee: rigth, I missed the square in the denominator. So its job is to turn amount of $w$ to be $1$. And I actually meant $v:=(\sqrt{\frac{a}{a+2}},\sqrt{\frac{b}{b+2}},\sqrt{\frac{c}{c+2}})$

Let $x:=b+c$ and $y:=bc$. Then
$$a = \frac{4-bc}{b+c+bc}= \frac{4-y}{x+y}.$$
We would like to find a counterexample. That is, we would like to find $x,y$ with
$$
\frac{4-y}{x+y}+x+y< \frac{4-y}{x+y}x + y
$$
Multiplying through by $x+y$ and rearranging, we find that this is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align*}
4-y+(x+y)^2 &< (4-y)x+y(x+y)\\
x^2+y^2+2xy+4-y&<4x-yx+xy+y^2\\
f_y(x):=x^2+(2y-4)x+(4-y) < 0
\end{align*}
$$
Since $f_y(x)>0$ for $x$ large enough, $f_y(x)$ attains negative values if and only if it has disctinct real roots, which is equivalent to its discriminant being positive, or:
$$
\begin{align*}
(2y-4)^2 - 4(4-y) &> 0\\
4y^2-12y &>0\\
y(y-3) &>0
\end{align*}
$$
Because $a,b,c>0$, we must have $x,y>0$ and $y<4$. We now see, that we must in fact have $3<y<4$.
Finally, the minimal values of $f_y(x)$ is attained at $-(2y-4)/4=-y+2<0$ and $f_y(0)>0$, whence $f_y(x)>0$ for all $x,y$ corresponding to $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c>0$.
We conclude that no counterexamples exist. This proves the inequality.
